# Disable right column for this page

Tags: tikz-pgf, formatting

I have a long, two column document. In one of these pages, I added a graphic that spans exactly the right half of that page and touches the edge; done with this code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[anchor =north east, inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] at (current page.north east) {\includegraphics[width=0.5\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{gfx/portraitmod}};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The problem is that the text on the right column just flows through the image, which looks pretty ugly.

How can I tell Latex to not use the left or right column for a given page (e.g., this page), without disrupting any other typesetting?

Comment: Remove `overlay`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `overlay` option to the `tikzpicture` makes the picture to occupy no space and hence text flows over the picture. FYI, `remember picture` allows you to use the page anchors like `current page.north east`. Further, you have to use `\columnwidth` and `\textheight` instead of `\paperwidth` and `\paperheight`.

Solution is to remove `overlay` option.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
  \lipsum[1-3]
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[anchor =north east, inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] at (current page.north east)
        {\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth,height=\textheight]{example-image}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

On the other hand, if you want the graphic to cover the right side of the *paper*, use `afterpage` package and issue `\afterpage{\mbox{}\pagebreak}`:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{tikz,afterpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
  \afterpage{\mbox{}\pagebreak}
  \lipsum[1]
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[anchor =north east, inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] at (current page.north east)
        {\includegraphics[width=0.5\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]